# Contract compile error in Dapp tutorial (wine collection marketplace)

Tags: smart-contracts, ligo, nft

I'm trying to run through this tutorial on dapp development with ligo (https://tezos.com/developers/tutorials/nft-ligo-marketplace/) and am running into an error. In the "NFT Marketplace Contract" section, when I try to compile the contract I get the following message:

[image]

I tried updating the following commands from the tutorial to the latest version of ligo (0.66.0):

TAQ_LIGO_IMAGE=ligolang/ligo:0.64.2 taq ligo --command "install @ligo/fa"

TAQ_LIGO_IMAGE=ligolang/ligo:0.64.2 taq compile nft.jsligo

I've also got the following (potentially related) problem within vscode:

[image]

Any help on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Which version of Taqueria do you use ?
What is the return code of "taq ... --command "install @ligo/fa" ?
Do you have the esy.json file on your project folder ?
Do you have a .ligo folder on your project folder ?

Comment: Struggling at the same point. Return of TAQ_LIGO_IMAGE=ligolang/ligo:0.64.2 taq ligo --command "install @ligo/fa" is too long to post it here in the comments.

Comment: The error message indicates that there's a permission issue (for taq) while trying to create directories and temporary files in the .ligo directory.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is missing, that you need to create a read and writeable .ligo folder first.

Answer (score 0):

Up-to-date version here : https://github.com/marigold-dev/training-nft-1

The version on tezos.com is old and very painful to update.
I will have a look on how to simplify the way to update content on Tezos.com without losing too much time

Comment: btw : everything here is updated with last ligo version (https://www.marigold.dev/learn). 
Thinking on moving all to Tezos official doc soon